# eSATA drives keeps disappearing, only reappears after reboot

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, motherboard, esata

I have one relatively fat PC at home, that I use as a server, a back-up drive included, and as my gaming PC as well.

The Operating System is *Windows 7 Ultimate* 64 bit.

I currently have an [ASUS Maximus IV Extreme](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/MAXIMUS_IV_EXTREME/) Motherboard, which includes the following:

```
Intel® P67(B3) chipset : *1
 2 x SATA 6Gb/s port(s), red
 4 x SATA 3Gb/s port(s), gray
  Support Raid 0, 1, 5, 10
Marvell® PCIe 9182 controller : *1
 2 x SATA 6Gb/s port(s), red
JMicron® JMB362 controller : 
 2 x eSATA 3Gb/s port(s), red
```

I have all these slots filled with different Internal Hard Drives (ranging from 2TB Drives to 4TB Drives, and 1 OCZ Vertex 4 SSD), including the 2x eSATA ports. The drives run perfectly, except that after a seemingly random amount of time/actions/operations the 2 drives on the eSATA ports virtually disappear.

They do not show up when opening the 'My Computer' directory, nor when I open the Hardware Manager tool from the Control Panel.

The only reappear once I have restarted my system.

I have tried a few things in the BIOS (Changing from AHCI to IDE mode), but I may be doing it wrong or just doing the wrong things, since it did not yield a positive result.